# Browser not refreshing with component - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel view component not refreshing in browser.

I’ve tried hard refresh, cleared browser cache, runbacl devs, run npm, nothing works. Anybody else have this issue? Please help

Comment: Hello, to increase your chances of being answered, check this guide to know properly about how to describe your problem: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try `php artisan view:clear`.

Also, check the `\storage\framework\views` folder to see if the views are truly cleared from the cache.